# What sorting algorithm does Java adopt?

Tags: java, sorting

What kind of algorithm does Collections.sort in Jana use? It might be similar to quick sort, I guess. Java has Array.sort, too. Are they different?

Comment: What does the API tell you?

Comment: `Collections.sort` forwards to `Arrays.sort(collection.toArray())`. Which in turn uses several different algorithms depending on input type, for example [TimSort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort). Or a fancy parallel fork-join sort in Java 8.

Comment: I'm now using Java7 and Java8. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all of these kinds of questions, the documentation is always the best place to start.

The [Collection.Sort documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) states that it uses "a stable, adaptive, iterative mergesort" and that "the implementation was adapted from Tim Peters's list sort for Python ([TimSort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort))."

> The sorting algorithm is a **modified mergesort** (in which the merge is
>   omitted if the highest element in the low sublist is less than the
>   lowest element in the high sublist).

From the [Array documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(byte[]))

> Implementation note: The sorting algorithm is a **Dual-Pivot Quicksort**
>   by Vladimir Yaroslavskiy, Jon Bentley, and Joshua Bloch. This
>   algorithm offers O(n log(n)) performance on many data sets that cause
>   other quicksorts to degrade to quadratic performance, and is typically
>   faster than traditional (one-pivot) Quicksort implementations.

Comment: You better link to more recent documentation :) Java 7 [replaced modified mergesort](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6804124) and the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) has changed implementation notes.

Comment: Whoops. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Thank you so much. I should have check the documents first.